# Stop billing method at Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I have added my Credit card information at Google cloud services which provided me 1 year of free subscription. Now, I wanted to remove the card information and wanted to stop billing.

What's the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close your billing account take the following steps:

> To close a billing account you must be a billing administrator on the
>   account. Billing accounts cannot be deleted.
>
> Note: Before you close an active billing account, you must move its
>   associated projects to another billing account or disable billing for
>   its projects.
>
> To close an account:
>
> Go to the Cloud Platform Console. Open the console left side menu and
>   select Billing  Billing If you have more than one billing account,
>   select the billing account name. Click Close billing account. Note:
>   After you close your billing account, we will bill you for the usage
>   you accrued prior to cancelling your service. This bill will be the
>   last bill you receive, unless you reactivate service.

Taken from https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653?hl=en